# How to reliably send network request on Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Supposed I have an Activity that wanted to send a network request (e.g. Http request) to a server. How should I go about implementing it?

I could

1. From the Activity, create an AsyncTask.
2. Send a Http request message to server inside the AsyncTask.
3. Wait for an acknowledge response message from server inside the AsyncTask.

However it is possible that messages are dropped and the AsyncTask continue running without ever receiving a response message therefore leaking memory.

I could also

1. Start a worker thread from Activity.
2. Send request inside worker thread.
3. Wait for acknowledge response inside worker thread.
4. If timeout without receiving a response, resend request message.

However it is possible for the user to "quit" the activity (by receiving a phone call, pressing home button etc.). How then should I handle such scenario? What happens if the response message arrive but the activity is not in onResume state? Do i just drop the request and resend a new request when the Activity is created again?

I am sure this is a common use case but I am unable to find much discussion on how to implement a reliable way to do it that can handle the different possible situation in an Activity lifecycle. Please point me in the right direction. Thank you.